# ImmNotifyIME() with empty string?

Tags: windows, winapi, string

I have doubt on ImmNotifyIME() function.

```
ImmNotifyIME(hwnd, NI_COMPOSITIONSTR, CPS_CANCEL, 0);
```

If I created the hwnd with empty string. Then, what will it return? Whether it will through a error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ImmNotifyIME` takes a handle to an *input context*, not an hwnd.  But, assuming you really meant

```
HIMC himc = ImmGetContext(hwnd);
ImmNotifyIME(ImmGetContext(hwnd), NI_COMPOSITIONSTR, CPS_CANCEL, 0);
ImmReleaseContext(himc);
```

then that will successfully clear any pending composition, if one is open or not.